# Switching rows and columns for an import file

Tags: data

How can I generate a code for switching rows and columns of a random .txt file? The data inside that file may contain strings, which must be switched too.

I import the data in a table format, but I want to export the same file with just rows and columns interchanged.

A quick way of doing it?

The data can be for example:

[image]
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample txt file so that we can work with it?

Comment: Are you looking for `Transpose` ?

Comment: I tried with transpose, but when I'm exporting the file, it doesn't look like the input file

Comment: Based on your example, have you tried exporting with "TSV" as the format (third argument of export)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below an example where I swap second and third row and I all the columns:

```
data = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

(* Rearrange rows *)
data[[{1, 2, 3}]] = data[[{1, 3, 2}]];

(* Rearrange columns *)    
data[[;; , {1, 2, 3}]] = data[[;; , {3, 1, 2}]]
```

> {{"c", "a", "b"}, {6, 4, 5}, {3, 1, 2}}

```
(* Export in txt file *)
Export["test.txt", data, "Table"]
```

Next time please provide a .txt file to work with, not just an image of it.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I couldn't find the option for uploading the file (except the image!

Comment: @Guillermo There is no direct way to upload a file here, but you can create e.g. [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com) and provide a link to it.

Comment: Alright, for future posts, thank you!